# Trouble converting html layout from table to divs & css

Tags: html, css

I have an old web application that I'm trying to update. In the original design HTML tables were used extensively to layout both non-tabular and tabular data. Now I'm trying to "modernize" the app by removing most the HTML table layout and replacing it with divs and CSS. Below is an example of a small amount of information that was in a table and I've converted to divs and CSS. My problem is the CSS is not very generic so extending it to the level of the entire app doesn't seem practicle. Unfortunately, I can't think of a better way to lay this out. I'm looking for some ideas of a better way to perform this type of layout using divs and CSS.

This is just a small page that I've converted. I have other screens of this app that have similar layouts with much larger amounts of data and I'd like a suggestion of a good approach for laying it out. I'm not looking for someone to rewrite my code. I just need a fresh idea that doesn't require four lines of CSS for every cell of the old table layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<style>
#headerData {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CCC;
    left: 10;
    width:800px;
    top: 10;
    height: 130px;
    clear: both;
    border: medium solid #999;
}
#headerData h2 {
    top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}
.dataLabels{
    text-align: right;
}
.dataFields {
    text-align: left;
    color: #00F;
    padding-left: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: thin solid #999;
}
.rowOne {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    height: 19px;
}
.rowTwo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    height: 19px;
}
.rowThree {
    position: absolute;
    top: 96px;
    height: 19px;
}
.colOne {
    left: 15px;
    width: 151px;
}
.colTwo {
    left: 171px;
    width: 80px;
}
.colTwoSpanThree {
    left: 171px;
    width: 265px;
}
.colThree {
    left: 260px;
    width: 92px;
}
.colThreeSpanTwo {
    left: 260px;
    width: 243px;
}
.colFour {
    left: 360px;
    width: 143px;
}
.colFourFive {
    left: 440px;
    width: 65px;
}
.colFive {
    left: 517px;
    width: 64px;
}
.colFiveSix {
    left: 512px;
    width: 272px;
}
.colSix {
    left: 589px;
    width: 122px;
}
.colSeven {
    left: 720px;
    width: 69px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #9C0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="headerData">
  <h2>WORK ORDER</h2>
  <div class="rowOne colOne dataLabels">Order:</div>
  <div class="rowOne colTwo dataFields">3105-001</div>
  <div class="rowOne colThree dataLabels">Parent:</div>
  <div class="rowOne colFour dataFields">3105</div>
  <div class="rowOne colFive dataLabels">Project:</div>
  <div class="rowOne colSix dataFields">2013 DiskProj</div>
  <div class="rowOne colSeven">Open</div>
  <div class="rowTwo colOne dataLabels">Customer:</div>
  <div class="rowTwo colTwo dataFields">MICR01</div>
  <div class="rowTwo colThreeSpanTwo dataFields">Microsoft Corporation</div>
  <div class="rowTwo colFive dataLabels">Estimate:</div>
  <div class="rowTwo colSix dataFields">5248 Rev A</font></div>
  <div class="rowThree colOne dataLabels">Item:&nbsp;<span style="font-family: Wingdings; background-color: #fff;">&#254;</span></div>
  <div class="rowThree colTwoSpanThree dataFields">2016 Office DVD</div>
  <div class="rowThree colFourFive dataLabels">Desc:</div>
  <div class="rowThree colFiveSix dataFields">2016 Ofc Distribution Disk</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stick with the tables. What will you achieve by reimplementing your layout? Absolutely positioning your page with specified pixel coordinates is a sidegrade at best.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to add [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) to your project. Bootstrap has inbuilt classes that support "row" and "col", through which you can easily mock a table structure.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
</div>
```

It is a good idea to define height and width as percentages rather than actual pixel to support window resizing. (Although there may be definitive cases where a strict pixel definition is required).